# What do the numbers on the axis mean when visualizing clusters in 2-dimensions?

Tags: python, cluster-computing, data-visualization, k-means, pca

I followed the codes in [this link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48693/perform-k-means-clustering-over-multiple-columns)

What do the numbers on the x-axis and y-axis mean in this plot? Why they are discrete numbers?

[image]

When I used my own data, it gives me this kind of plot, I can't understand what the plot is trying to say.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As they are working with more than two dimensions (features), they are using [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to project the data into two dimensions (that do not need to correspond to any of the dimensions of the original data) so it can be plotted.

So each of the data points are projected into the dimensions PCA1 and PCA2, which are real-valued (not discrete)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I edited my question, I added a plot I got by using my data, you mean the values represent the real value (variance??) of PC1 & PC2? I got some negative numbers on the second plot.

Comment: can you share the code you used for your plot? how many dimensions does your data have? have you standardized the data? The PCA components (PCA1 and PCA2) try to account for as much variability from the data as possible

Comment: Hi please check this link: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/56826/how-can-i-adjust-the-legend-when-visualizing-clusters-in-two-dimensions/56827?noredirect=1#comment62514_56827 , this is my another question regarding to the adjusting the legend of the plot and the codes are in that question.(Originally I have 61 dimensions)

Comment: with the information that I extracted from the code and plots what I can guess is that there is a component (PCA1) that allows you to separate the data into clearly delimited clusters. So when applying K-means with 10 clusters you get a cluster for each of those "columns" you see in the plot

Comment: Thanks, so what kind of information can we get from these 'columns'? If we have two different plots, please see my edit, I added another plot I got after normalising the data, and the clusters are no long 'columns', how can we compare them? Or we can just have a vague concept of how these 10 clusters distribute?

Comment: Okay, I saw your new edit. So as you can see in the last plot if you were to project all your data into a "diagonal" line which we will call PCA1 you will get those "columns" that you see in the other plots. I don't think you can directly compare the pictures, you are just creating two new projections for your data

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wonder if we can see which clustering result is better? I used exactly the same codes to generate these two plots, the difference is the first one is using the original data, the second one used z-score normalized data, I'm kind of confused why the plot seem so different? I actually also tried Min-Max normalized data, and it's similar with the first plot, giving me 'columns', can I say Min-Max gives me better result than Z-score?